Как получить больше 200 участников из телеграм группы?
не понимаю почему не удается получить больше 200 участников телеграм группы, как то помогает только перебор по фильтру но он не отдает удалённые телеграм аккаунты в группе (это те у которых только один userid и больше никаких данных)
Все что находил либо уже старое и неактуальное либо так же не работает
require('dotenv').config();
const { TelegramClient, Api } = require("telegram");
const { StringSession } = require("telegram/sessions");
const input = require("input");

if (!process.env.API_ID || !process.env.API_HASH) {
  console.error("API_ID и API_HASH в .env файле.");
  process.exit(1);
}

const apiId = parseInt(process.env.API_ID);
const apiHash = process.env.API_HASH;

const stringSession = new StringSession("");
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const generateHash = (ids) => {
  let hash = 0;
  for (const id of ids) {
    hash = hash ^ (hash >> 21);
    hash = hash ^ (hash << 35);
    hash = hash ^ (hash >> 4);
    hash = hash + id;
  }
  return hash;
};

(async () => {
  const client = new TelegramClient(stringSession, apiId, apiHash, {
    connectionRetries: 5,
  });

  await client.start({
    phoneNumber: async () => await input.text("Номер ?"),
    password: async () => await input.text("Пароль ?"),
    phoneCode: async () => await input.text("Код ?"),
    onError: (err) => console.log(err),
  });

  const groupId = await input.text("ID группы: ");
  const allParticipants = [];
  const uniqueParticipants = new Set();

  try {
    let offset = 0;
    const limit = 200;
    let hash = 200;
    let nextBatch = true;

    while (nextBatch) {
      try {
        const participants = await client.invoke(
          new Api.channels.GetParticipants({
            channel: groupId,
            filter: new Api.ChannelParticipantsSearch({ q: "" }), 
            offset: offset,
            limit: limit,
            hash: hash,
          })
        );

        if (participants.participants.length > 0) {
          const ids = [];
          participants.participants.forEach((user) => {
            const userId = user.userId.valueOf();
            if (!uniqueParticipants.has(userId)) {
              uniqueParticipants.add(userId);
              const telegramUser = participants.users.find((u) => u.id.valueOf() === userId);
              const firstName = telegramUser?.firstName || "Не указано";
              const lastName = telegramUser?.lastName || "Не указано";
              const username = telegramUser?.username || "Не указано";

              allParticipants.push({
                group_id: groupId,
                id: telegramUser.id.valueOf(),
                username: username,
                first_name: firstName,
                last_name: lastName,
                phone: telegramUser.phone || "",
                is_premium: telegramUser.premium ? "Yes" : "No",
              });
              ids.push(userId);
            }
          });

          offset += participants.participants.length;
          hash = generateHash(ids);
          nextBatch = participants.participants.length === limit; 
        } else {
          nextBatch = false;  
        }

      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Ошибка при извлечении участников:", error);
        nextBatch = false; 
      }

      await delay(2000); 
    }

    console.log("Извлечённые участники:", allParticipants);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Ошибка при загрузке участников:", error);
  } finally {
    await client.disconnect();
    process.exit(0);
  }
})();

Или сама телега заблокировала такой способ получения списка участников?
